# do-release-upgrade complains that system out of date

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, upgrade

That's just that, `do-release-upgrade` complains that the system is not up to date, even though `apt upgrade` and `apt dist-upgrade` show everything IS up to date. And you're yanking handfuls of hair out. What is going on?

Answer (score 0):

I've posted before about some problems caused by thrice-accursed Libreoffice 5.3 build. Well, it's been years, but the darned thing came back to bite! I'm certain the repositories for it are long dead and of course nothing can be updated, especially considering that I don't even have that version installed anymore. But of course my monster of a computer is still very much alive and very well. Successfully upgraded to 18.04LTS today.

So, to be able to do the upgrade, turns out had to clean up the repository list. Start `software-properties-gtk` and uncheck all the repositories except the main Ubuntu ones. The Libreoffice 5.3 specifically was still there and still selected. Maybe because I naively installed it with Ubuntu Software forever ago.

Anyways, after that list got cleaned up `do-release-upgrade` ran without any issues. But talk about a pest of a package!

So if somebody else's upgrade gets stuck like that claiming stuff is out of date, clean up the repository list and everything should go off without a hitch.